# UIWebView iOS document.getElementByID does not work

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am having a really weird bug for `UIWebView`, I load a very simple html into the `UIWebView`:

`[self.webview loadHTMLString:@"<html><body><div id='hello'>hello world</div></body></html>" baseURL:nil];`

and then call 4 lines below:

```
NSString *body = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML"];

NSString *helloValue = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"document.getElementByID('hello').value"];

NSString *helloOuter = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
          @"document.getElementByID('hello').outerHTML"];

NSString *helloInner = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                @"document.getElementByID('hello').innerHTML"];

NSString *helloElement = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
          @"document.getElementByID('hello')"];
```

Only the first line, using getElementsByTagName return me the correct body html, all other lines just return me an empty string @"". What can go wrong with my code? How can I get the `div` that has an id of `hello`

Comment: Try using a semi-colon at the end of each JS statement.

Comment: If you switch the top two calls, does `helloValue` have a value?

Comment: I tried to comment this line: `NSString *body = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML"];`. It still does not return anything

Comment: There is no `value` attribute for an HTMLElement. What are you trying to get there?

Comment: I am trying to get is the content inside the `<div id='hello'>hello world</div>`, I tried with `value, innerHTML and outerHTML`, I am not sure if this is the correct way?

Comment: Use `innerHTML` to get the HTML and text nodes inside an element. That second call is failing, which causes all other JS to fail.

Comment: I also tried to leave only the line with innerHTML left but the result is still empty.

Comment: Ops, I know what's wrong, I misspell the method it has to be `document.getElementById` with the lowercase `Id` not `ID`. Anyways, thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem: it was my stupid misspelling, `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID`